# I have a problem with opening text file that I created (<fstream>)

Tags: c++, fstream

The problem is that I name a string "name" as a name of my text file in one function. On the other I make a function to read that file. I call the same string as a name of the text document but the program don't show the text I add in the file.

```
ifstream file1(name);
file1.open(name);
file1 >> dis;
cout << dis;
file1.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the file is opened correctly?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: It is always a good idea to test the state of a stream after every operation. Even if doing it doesn't provides any hints on how to fix the problem, it at least tells you were the problem is.

Comment: I haven’t checked, but I suspect that trying to open the file for the second time is the problem. `ifstresm file1(name);` opens the file and connects it to the object `file1`. The call `file1.open(name);` tries to do the same thing again. I suspect that that’s not allowed. Try removing the second open and see if that fixes things. Also, you don’t need to call `file1.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Pete Backer the program still can't open the file.But thanks for the help 
I appreciate it .